# Return image path in Laravel API resource

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am build a laravel 5.8 API only application and want to return the image path as path of an API resource so that it can be consumed inside an image source attribute. So this is what I have to done to achieve this.
1. I ran `php artisan storgae:link` command to create the symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`

2. First I store the image inside a `productImages` table when a new product is successfully created like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // create & store the product
    if ($product = Product::create([
        'name'      => $request->name,
        'category'  => $request->category,
        'status'    => $request->status,
        'price'     => $request->price,
        'interest'  => $request->interest,
    ])) {
        // store the product image
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $destinationPath = "public/images/products";
        $filename = 'pramopro_' . $product->name . '_' . $product->id . '.' . $file->extension();

        Storage::putFileAs($destinationPath, $file, $filename);

        ProductImage::create([
            'product_id'    => $product->id,
            'name'          => $filename
        ]);
    }

    // return new product
    return new ProductResource($product);
}
```

3. Return the image path in the ProductResource like this

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'        => $this->id,
        'name'      => $this->name,
        'category'  => $this->category,
        'status'    => $this->status,
        'price'     => $this->price,
        'interest'  => $this->interest,
        'hidden'    => $this->hidden,
        'imageUrl'  => asset('images/products/' . $this->image->name)
    ];
}
```

Testing it on my local serve I get a path like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "dpk",
    "category": "fuel",
    "status": "open",
    "price": 100000,
    "interest": 0.2,
    "hidden": 0,
    "imageUrl": "http://localhost:8000/images/products/pramopro_dpk_1.jpeg"
  }
```

When I try to view the image by putting `http://localhost:8000/images/products/randomtext_1.jpeg` in my browser, I get `404 not found` error.

But this `http://localhost:8000/storage/images/products/pramopro_dpk_1.jpeg` displays the image as expected.

How should I be retrieving the image path for it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the asset() function puts you in your public directory, you need to add /storage to the path of your file , try this in your toArray function

```
'imageUrl'  => asset('storage/images/products/' . $this->image->name)
```

Personal note , handling media in laravel can be a headache i personally use LaravelMediaLibrary by spaite

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary

it has really helped me and made handling media as easy as it can get especially when handling multiple media for the same model

Comment: I will check out `LaravelMediaLibrary` package. I actually had to add the `storage` to the path.